# Ownership modifiers with manual reference counting

Tags: objective-c

What happens when you use the Objective-C onwership modifiers (`__strong, __weak, __unsafe_unretained`) with manual reference counting? Do any of them modify the behavior of are just ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clang -E -dM` shows the definitions of the built-in macros:

```
$ clang -E -dM -x objective-c /dev/null | egrep  "weak|strong|unsafe"
#define __strong 
#define __unsafe_unretained 
#define __weak __attribute__((objc_gc(weak)))
```

As you can see, `__strong` and `__unsafe_unretained` are defined as empty macros,
and `__weak` is defined as something that (as I understand it) is only relevant in the
(no longer supported) garbage-collected environment.

**So in short:** The ownership modifiers are **ignored** with Manual Reference Counting. That makes sense because it is *your* responsibility to maintain the reference counts.

The situation is slightly different with properties:

```
@property(strong) id x;            // same as "retain"
@property(weak) id y;              // syntax error with MRC
@property(unsafe_unretained) id z; // same as "assign"
```

And just for the sake of completeness: With ARC the ownership modifiers are built-in
macros defined as follows:

```
$ clang -E -dM -x objective-c -fobjc-arc /dev/null | egrep  "weak|strong|unsafe"
#define __strong __attribute__((objc_ownership(strong)))
#define __unsafe_unretained __attribute__((objc_ownership(none)))
#define __weak __attribute__((objc_ownership(weak)))
```